# Execute link using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, hyperlink, execute

The following link opens a video when clicked:

```
<a href="<?php echo  $rows['image1'] ; ?> " rel="vidbox" title="<?php  echo  $rows['name']."          <br>".nl2br($rows['detail']) ; ?>" id="m2"><?php echo  $rows['name'] ; ?></a>
```

Can I run/execute this link using Javascript/PHP as if someone clicked on this link?

Comment: Link :<a href="<?php echo  $rows['image1'] ; ?> " rel="vidbox" title="<?php  echo  $rows['name']."<br>".nl2br($rows['detail']) ; ?>" id="m2"><?php echo  $rows['name'] ; ?></a>

Comment: check whether php code is resulting desired output, if yes you can use the above anchor tag.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to click on a link using javascript / jquery. You can trigger the bound events using `$('#m2').click()` but it will not open the url. What you could do is, use document.location.href to open the page

```
document.location.href = document.getElementById('m2').href;
```

Comment: Dear Joyce thanks for prompt reply I am not clear as how do i execute link Link :<a href="<?php echo $rows['image1'] ; ?> " rel="vidbox" title="<?php echo $rows['name']."<br>".nl2br($rows['detail']) ; ?>" id="m2"><?php echo $rows['name'] ; ?></a>.................. pls help.. the link ok and working fine

Comment: What do you mean by executing the link? Do you want to open that url? If so, you can use `document.location.href` for that. If not, please explain your exact requirement.

Comment: When do you want this action to trigger?

Comment: to explain this refer the link http://m2k-education.com/samplevideo1.php... i could form the link using ajax click on this link should display the video but same is not happening. This link is same as normal link displayed........ Note here efforts are to hide the video file name being displayed.The idea is ajax will form the link, and i want the video to be displayed .. By execut i mean run the link as if some one had clicked it

Comment: This website is e-learning website.  List of videos are available for viewing (e-lectures.) By clicking the name a video pops up. However one can download the video by right clicking the link. So as to avoid this i thought of ajax. A click on a link (for list of videos) will pass the id of the video and will form a link (refer http://m2k-education.com/samplevideo1.php) on this page I had both links default(click on this plays video)  as well as where i am using ajax.Problem : click on "Link used to call ajax" forms the link properly on right hand side but when clicked do not open up the video.

Comment: If this link  open up the video(link formed by ajax)  i can execute or run this automatically.as if some one had clicked it. Could not understand this .

Comment: I don't think that will solve your problem completely. Anyone with a little technical knowledge can still download the video. Since you are using Mootools, I don' think I can be of much help (I'm a jQuery person). But you could try `$('m2').fireEvent('click');`

Comment: well joyce appreciate this...is there a solution in jquery.. appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you are using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#m2').click();
});
```

Where `m2` is the ID of the link to be clicked.

Comment: thanks a lot i am using mootools.js,  swfobject.js, videobox.js can u pls suggest a javascript to execute query