# Is it possible to execute javascript on the press of a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link:

```
<a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">
    SOMENAME <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</a>
```

Now, I want to execute javascript whenever the above hyperlink is pressed, without adding any code inside `<a href ... /a>`.

Is this possible?

**Edit:**

This question is different from questions asked earlier because I don't have any `<id>` inside `<a href ... /a>`.

Also, I cannot add code inline inside `<a href ... /a>`. I somehow need to track the press of hyperlink, and then execute javascript. Also, I have many such hyperlinks and I need to track them differently.

Comment: Look at [Event Listenters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute link using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498101/execute-link-using-javascript) and a million other resources found by searching SO or Google.

Comment: It's bad practice, but you can. you can add a 'onclick' on the tag or bind click  with jquery. Then inside that function add the preventDefault before your desired js  code  snippet.

Comment: @Rob In that question `id` was provided inside the `<a href .. >`, so that was easy, but I don't have that in my case. so, not a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either inline:

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" onclick="return myFunction();">link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction () {
        // return false => does not navigate to href
        // return true => navigate to href
    }
</script>
```

Or add click listener via JS:

```
var link = document.querySelector('a');
link.onclick = function() {

}
```

**EDIT**: In case of multiple links:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.onclick = function() {

    }
}
```

**EDIT2**: If you want to discriminate by the **href** attribute content:

```
a[href]        an a element with a "href" attribute (CSS 2)
a[href="bar"]  an a element whose "href" attribute value is exactly equal to "bar" (CSS 2)
a[href~="bar"] an a element whose "href" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar" (CSS 2)
a[href^="bar"] an a element whose "href" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar" (CSS 3)
a[href$="bar"] an a element whose "href" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar" (CSS 3)
a[href*="bar"] an a element whose "href" attribute value contains the substring "bar" (CSS 3)
a[href|="en"]  an a element whose "href" attribute has a hyphen-separated list of values beginning (from the left) with "en" (CSS 2)
```

So you would have:

```
var link = document.querySelector('a[href="theValueIamLookingFor"]');
link.onclick = function() {

}
```

**EDIT3**: You could also test the **href** values within the for loop:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.onclick = function() {
        switch(link.href) {
            case 'www.google.com':
                // Do something
                break;
            case 'https://stackoverflow.com':
                // Do something else
                break;
            default:
                return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @kashish Loop and do it for every of them?

Comment: can I use the value inside href if I want to execute javascript only for one of them?

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess the behavior is the same as inline, if you return true from the JS function, then you'll navigate to the href value

Comment: Actually, I have multiple <a> and I need to track them differently.

Comment: Then you've to find your own discriminator, by the containing class for example, then the selector would be **document.querySelector('.containingClass a')**

Comment: Take a look at the differents CSS3 selectors, you should find what you want

Comment: Based on your answer, I write [this simple code](http://i.imgur.com/JKww0Ow.png), but I don't know why it isn't working. Pls help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150644/discussion-between-kashish-and-quentin-morrier).

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comment that you may have multiple  tags in your document the simplest method is to select an element with a particular href.

```
$('a[href^="https://somelink.com"]').click(function() {
    alert('you pressed me');
});
```

you do not need to edit or add something to your 'a' tag.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is my [code](https://codepen.io/paraspl01t/pen/BdKVrW?editors=1010#0) works perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the value that is passed in the href attribute, you could do something like :

**EDIT**

```
$( "a" ).each(function(){
  if($(this).attr("href") === "https://google.com" )
    console.log('hey');
});
```

Comment: I have mentioned in question that I can't add code inside <a href..> . I somehow need to track the press of hyperlink, but I don't know how?

Comment: Do you have the value of href that is passed onto the a tag?

Comment: Also, don't use `javascript:` "links".

Comment: @kashish Could you post markup on which you are trying to do?